# How to ask for "free-range eggs" in Chinese?

Tags: translation

Quick question: I will be going to a local supermarket here in Taipei. How do I ask for "free-range chicken eggs"? According to google translate its "自由放养的鸡蛋." Is this correct?

Comment: well, may you consider the cantonese term "走地雞蛋" ;) even the wiki pages has this translation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free-range_eggs https://zh-yue.wikipedia.org/wiki/走地雞蛋

Comment: Leaving aside the use and abuse of terms like "free-range" and "organic", if you ever come to South-East Aside, you say 甘榜鸡蛋, "Gān bǎng Eggs", "Gān bǎng" is a transliteration of the Indo-Malay word "Kampong", meaning a "village" The idea being that eggs are produced by chickens that run merrily around in the village, eating worms and whatever food scraps that happen to lie around which sounds "romantic" but totally false, just  like your 土鸡蛋 or 笨鸡蛋, (BTW, 笨 means "stupid" or "silly") One wonders to whom that term refers to?

Answer (score 5):

It is literally correct, but no one would use it, except Mr. Shakespeare.

土鸡蛋 or 笨鸡蛋 is the one.

And the universal is 家养的, e.g. 家养的鸡蛋, 家养的鸭子, 家养的鹅...

In my hometown, people also say 溜达鸡, 溜达 means stroll.

Comment: 家养的鸡 can be living in a cage for its entire life, it is still better than the factory farm though

Answer (score 3):

Colloquially it is known as **土鸡蛋**.

The *Pleco* Dictionary by Pleco defines it as:

> eggs laid by home-kept chicken; free-range eggs

Luckily for you *[Liang'an](https://www.moedict.tw/~%E5%9C%9F%E9%9B%9E%E8%9B%8B)* (a Taiwanese based dictionary) also mentions:

> 指農家放養在山坡的雞所下的蛋。蛋殼較厚、蛋清較稠，營養價值較高。陸 也作「笨雞蛋」。

Which also supports the idea of the eggs being "free-range," it also mentions that Mainland also sometimes refers to them as **笨鸡蛋**.

Comment: 土鸡蛋 sounds like 'local farm's chicken's eggs', yes they are likely be free-range-chicken's eggs, but 'free-range-chicken' doesn't translated back to 土鸡

Comment: @TangHo Actually, most dictionaries translate 土鸡 as "free-range chicken," and Chinese dictionaries also mention that 土鸡 means something along the lines of “放养于野外，不以人工饲料饲养的.”

Comment: And I would say the term 土鸡 also implies 'local chicken' which the English term 'free-range chicken' doesn't imply.

Comment: @TangHo Sure, but everything is about context.

Answer (score 3):

The term could be regional. I will suggest 散养鸡的鸡蛋 or散养鸡的蛋. Maybe 散养的鸡蛋 or  散养鸡蛋 can also work.

Answer (score 1):

'自由放养的鸡蛋' is almost there (what? the eggs run free?), but '自由放养鸡隻的鸡蛋'(free-range chicken's egg) would be more accurate.

However, it is too wordy for a commercial product's name, I think '放养鸡蛋' is a more suitable translation in marketing sense.

Basically, most people refer '自由放养的鸡' as '放养鸡' because the full description is really a mouthful.

Answer (score 0):

土鸡蛋 or 柴鸡蛋。You can also add "散养”，such as “散养土鸡蛋”，“散养柴鸡蛋”